# How to retrieve Link from Atom feed using SyndicationFeed and limiting number of items

Tags: c#, asp.net, atom-feed, rss-reader, syndicationfeed

I'm a bit new to asp.net so please bear with me...

I am trying to read and display an Atom feed from a WordPress site.

Scrounging the web, I was able to put together the following code in the Codebehind:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(myURL);
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

foreach (var item in feed.Items)
{

    Response.Write(item.PublishDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt"));
    Response.Write("<br/>");
    Response.Write(item.Title.Text);

}

reader.Close();
```

This works perfectly fine to display the date and time. Now here are the issues I need to solve:

**1) Retrieving the Link....**

Looking at the [SyndicationFeed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed(v=vs.110).aspx) posting on MSDN I can see there is a Links property, but I can't figure out how I can retrieve the `<link>` from the feed. Anyone know how to get this?

**2) Limiting the number of output...**

Right now, with the `foreach()` it displays every single entry in the feed. Any ideas how I can limit it to only show the newest x number?

Can i do something like...

```
while (var item in feed.Items < 5)
{

    Response.Write(item.PublishDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt"));
    Response.Write("<br/>");
    Response.Write(item.Title.Text);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Any ideas how I can limit it to only show the **newest** x number?
> - retrieving the collection of [`SyndicationLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationlink(v=vs.110).aspx)

You could (improve as needed/null checks, etc.):

```
//Newest by date/time and take x (e.g. 5)
foreach (var item in feed.Items.OrderByDescending(i => i.PublishDate).Take(5))
{
     //Get the Uris from SyndicationLink
     var theLinks = item.Links.Select(l => l.Uri.ToString()).ToList();

     //do something with them....
     var foo = string.Join(",", theLinks);

    ....
}
```

Hth....

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank You!